# Modify Superfish menu jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, superfish

I am trying to have superfish render the menu so that each menu column has a set of css that will allow me to give each menu column different css attributes. I.E. different text color, different background color, hover color.

For example the menu might be

```
Home | About Us:Meet the Team:Why Hire Us | Contact Us:Social Media | Our Services
```

Where "About Us" has two sub menu items and "Contact Us" has one sub menu item.

I would like to append styles to them so that .imMenu-Primary1... imMenu-PrimaryN is on each primary menu item and it's children. Also, I would like to append to each of their children something like this .imMenu-Childof-Primary1.... imMenu-Childof-PrimaryN. Or something similar that would allow me to style each primary menu item and it's children as a group.

Below is the Superfish file that I think is relevant.

Thank you in advance for your time and effort,

Tim

P.S. I am using Wordpress to generate the menu and can't or rather don't know how to walk the menu structure within Wordpress to add the css that way. I did notice though that super subs does walk the menu tree structure and am pretty sure it is possible to add css attributes using javascript. Which is why I suggested doing it that way. If however there is a better way to do it I am all ears. Thanks again.

```
;(function($){ // $ will refer to jQuery within this closure

$.fn.supersubs = function(options){
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.supersubs.defaults, options);
    // return original object to support chaining
    return this.each(function() {
        // cache selections
        var $$ = $(this);
        // support metadata
        var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $$.data()) : opts;
        // cache all ul elements and show them in preparation for measurements
        $ULs = $$.find('ul').show();
        // get the font size of menu.
        // .css('fontSize') returns various results cross-browser, so measure an em dash instead
        var fontsize = $('<li id="menu-fontsize">&#8212;</li>').css({
            'padding' : 0,
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'top' : '-999em',
            'width' : 'auto'
        }).appendTo($$)[0].clientWidth; //clientWidth is faster than .width()
        // remove em dash
        $('#menu-fontsize').remove();
        // loop through each ul in menu
        $ULs.each(function(i) { 
            // cache this ul
            var $ul = $(this);
            // get all (li) children of this ul
            var $LIs = $ul.children();
            // get all anchor grand-children
            var $As = $LIs.children('a');
            // force content to one line and save current float property
            var liFloat = $LIs.css('white-space','nowrap').css('float');
            // remove width restrictions and floats so elements remain vertically stacked
            $ul.add($LIs).add($As).css({
                'float' : 'none',
                'width' : 'auto'
            });
            // this ul will now be shrink-wrapped to longest li due to position:absolute
            // so save its width as ems.
            var emWidth = $ul[0].clientWidth / fontsize;
            // add more width to ensure lines don't turn over at certain sizes in various browsers
            emWidth += o.extraWidth;
            // restrict to at least minWidth and at most maxWidth
            if (emWidth > o.maxWidth)       { emWidth = o.maxWidth; }
            else if (emWidth < o.minWidth)  { emWidth = o.minWidth; }
            emWidth += 'em';
            // set ul to width in ems
            $ul.css('width',emWidth);
            // restore li floats to avoid IE bugs
            // set li width to full width of this ul
            // revert white-space to normal
            $LIs.css({
                'float' : liFloat,
                'width' : '100%',
                'white-space' : 'normal'
            })
            // update offset position of descendant ul to reflect new width of parent.
            // set it to 100% in case it isn't already set to this in the CSS
            .each(function(){
                var $childUl = $(this).children('ul');
                var offsetDirection = $childUl.css('left') !== undefined ? 'left' : 'right';
                $childUl.css(offsetDirection,'100%');
            });
        }).hide();

    });
};
// expose defaults
$.fn.supersubs.defaults = {
    minWidth        : 9,        // requires em unit.
    maxWidth        : 25,       // requires em unit.
    extraWidth      : 0         // extra width can ensure lines don't sometimes turn over due to slight browser differences in how they round-off     values
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to modify superfish. You just need to add classes to your menu markup and style them in the CSS file. Superfish doesn't control the CSS, it only extends the functionality of a standard CSS drop-down menu.

For example, if your markup looks like this you can just add some new classes to your `<li>` tags:

```
<ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about">
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Meet the Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Why Hire Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then just add the corresponding styles to your CSS using that class.

I notice you're not using superfish, but actually supersubs. This shouldn't be necessary anymore, see the note at http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/supersubs/

Comment: That I get. Unfortunately I forgot to mention I am using Wordpress and it is generating the markup for me. That's why I thought it would work to .addCss using supersubs since it walks through the entire structure in order to get maximum widths. I just can't wrap my head around it. I will edit my question to reflect that fact that I am using W Thank you.ordpress.

Comment: If you can't add classes you can always use selectors like `li:nth-child(0)`, `li:nth-child:(1)` etc. This wouldn't require any changes to the markup.

Comment: @nullabilty Wouldn't that require changing the code every time a menu item was added though to account for a new level of child depth? Also, it doesn't allow me to treat the children of a single primary menu item as a group and separately from all other menu items. For instance in the menu above the first menu item could be red while it's sub-menu items would be a lighter tint of red. Then the next menu items might be orange, green, blue with their respective sub-menu items being a tint of their top parent.